# Custom Table Collection Issues In Magento

Tags: magento

Below is my custom table collection and i have tried to show the data's in each page

```
 $domain = Mage::getModel('domain/domain')->getCollection();
         $domain->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage($page_number);
```

In my custom table have only 5 data's( Rows).  I would like to show the 3 data's for each page. When i pass the `$page_number` as 3 it will not show the empty. But it will show the 2nd page datas.

So how to find the last page & Last record of collection ?

Please suggest me..

Thanks All

Comment: Try adding `echo (string) $domain->getSelect()` and compare the queries for each page number.

Comment: I tried the above snippet, But didn't worked, So please Suggest me some other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior.

You can get the last page number by the code:

```
$lastPageNumber = $domain->getLastPageNumber();
```